# Prevent SSRS Filter Criteria From Removing Results with a Blank Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
Select FullName, ID, CASE WHEN TerritoryName IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE TerritoryName END AS Territory, SUM(Amount), Rank() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC) AS Rank
From Contact
Where...
Group By ...
```

In SSRS I have a dropdown filter named Territory which is populated through a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name AS Territory
FROM            Territory
ORDER BY Territory
```

The problem is, when I add the Territory filter in SSRS, the results that are marked as "Unknown" in the query, are automatically filtered out and not shown on the report.
How can I have these "unknowns" show on the report? Do I need to add "Unknown" to the drop down box in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your dropdown populate as:

```
SELECT Name AS Territory
FROM            Territory
UNION
SELECT 'Unknown'
```

So that the Unknown is an option

Comment: Wow, that was rediculously easy! Thanks Derek! It worked perfectly.